# How does Ralph know about the Castle's secret garden entrance?

Tags: zelda-oracle-of-ages

## Background

After beating [Mermaid's Cave](https://zelda.gamepedia.com/Mermaid%27s_Cave), you're sent to [Ambi's Palace](https://zelda.gamepedia.com/Ambi%27s_Palace) to invade while [Queen Ambi](https://zelda.gamepedia.com/Queen_Ambi) is gone.

Once at the castle gates, [Ralph](https://zelda.gamepedia.com/Ralph) is already there.

## Moment of confusion

Ralph mentions a secret entrance:

> *There should be a hidden entrance in the palace garden! I'll sneak in through there!*

After, Ralph explicitly says:

> *What? **"Why do I know about the hidden passage on my first trip here?" Nevermind!!!** I'm coming, Nayru!!!*

## Question

How did Ralph know about this secret passage? It doesn't seem to be explained in-game. Is there any background to this?

Comment: Because the developers programmed him to know about it. Based on what you've provided in your answer, it feels like a tongue-in-cheek joke in order to avoid fixing a plot hole.

Comment: @Kadima Wasn't looking for conclusions based on what I provided. Assuming what I provided is all that exists about it, it's obviously a joke - but there could be more to it. I'm looking for any buried information that may relate to this. If it's only a tongue-in-cheek joke, I'd understand. But implying the answer based on my statement; those who haven't played the game can assume the same. Leaving it at "it's a joke" without any prior research doesn't encourage progress, only attempts to halt it.

Comment: Queen Ambi is Ralphs ancestor. I thought it was maybe a hint to that fact. It may be possible that the information went down with generations. Or maybe he was there at some point before and link and you (the player) don't know about it. He does seem to just appear and then leave to somewhere else a lot, so there is no reason that it has to be his first visit. I assumed that link asked how he knew about it the first time, maybe he didn't want to explain why he was there before. This is not an answer, because it is speculation based on years old memories of a game that I didn't play in english.

Comment: This is not the only quirky plot hole in Oracle of Ages/Seasons. The quality and design on those two installments is not up to the (admittedly very high) bar that some of the other Zelda games have set.